# Black screen like a console when shutting down Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, shutdown

I have dual boot with Windows 10, different drives, Someone knows if this is normal? I recently installed R, Rstudio and a lot of other things but this is not the first time. If it is normal, then I don't have other choice than wait, but if I can change it and solve it. Thanks all.
[image]

Comment: I altered grub in my installation, so that instead of a blank screen, I can see various commands go scrolling by, and see if the machine hands on something.  You could do this by editing `/etc/default/grub` and changing the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` (rather than "quiet splash", you have a blank in quotes.  You will also see the bootup commands, rather than the pretty graphical display, and you must run `sudo update-grub` after the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue starting from yesterday. I'm using only Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) no any dual boot. When I shut down I see the same screen about one minute. But before yesterday it was shutting down in less than 10 seconds. Now I solved it, I just run `sudo update-grub` and `sudo shutdown -P now` and now it shutdowns as before. (I am not sure I solved it or it is solved by itself)